# Login redirects to home page and doesn't log in

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

When logging into the backend it redirects to the home page. If I try going to /wp-admin after it gives me the login again. I've tried deleting the htaccess, renaming the plugin and theme folders, clearing my cache, multiple browsers/computers/networks.

Not getting any error messages or anything like that. Never had this issue before, any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: Your browser caches redirects - if all the plugin and theme folders are renamed you should be able to open a clean new browser window, or an Incognito window.

Comment: Yeah I've tried multiple browsers clearing their cache and incognito windows. Still no luck.

Comment: You could try setting up a brand-new fresh install, then export & import your database, then only adjust wp-config.php (use the sample rather than copying from your current install, just plugin in the credentials) to point to the new database. That will tell you for sure whether the issue is in the database or files.